# mysterious "1" appearing at end of loaded content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm getting an extremely annoying and mysterious "1" displayed on the bottom right of each page from what i'm assuming is a mistake somewhere in the following ajax request and php code. The section marked as php loader is a seperate page by that name. the html is just li's with hash tags and rel="ajax"

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        //Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
    $.history.init(pageload);   
        //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');
        //Search for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {
        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;
        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
        //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   
        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        //hide the content and show the progress bar
        //$('#content').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        //run the ajax
        getPage();      
        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;

    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $('#loading').hide();   

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#content').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#content').fadeIn('fast');


            SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();


            }       
    });
}
    </script>

<?
/*php page loader*/
switch($_GET['page']) {
case '#code' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/code.php'); break;
case '#design' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/design.php'); break;
case '#illustration' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/illustration.php'); break;
case '#writing' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/writing.php'); break;
case '#links' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/links.php'); break;
case '#about' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/about.php'); break;
}
echo $page;

/*deep linking*/
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) )
{ 
} else {
header("Location: /mysite/#/index");
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 if only for the tag "mysterious"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The echo statement here is the cause.  `include` returns a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` on success/failure. You're assigning that to `$page` then echoing out `$page`:

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
  case '#code' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/code.php'); break;
  case '#design' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/design.php'); break;
  case '#illustration' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/illustration.php'); break;
  case '#writing' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/writing.php'); break;
  case '#links' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/links.php'); break;
  case '#about' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/about.php'); break;
}

// $page is 0 or 1 based on successfully including a file...
// Boolean TRUE will cast to 1 when printed
// FALSE won't print anything...
echo $page;
```

Comment: I'll check this when i get back to my computer, but would the jquery still work without the echo statement?

Comment: The jquery will be unaffected unless the included files are returning a string with the return keyword.  But since you're getting the 1 that appears not to be the case.  Should be fine.